# Symfony 2 passing a variable to a form class to dynamically create a hidden field in the form

Tags: forms, symfony

I am working on a blogging sort of tool on symfony 2 framework where a post can have many comments.  I have a one to many relationship established between posts and comments in the respective entities.  When a post is displayed on the home page, I want a comment form underneath it where users can post comments.  In order to post a comment, I have to pass a hidden field in the form for the postID but I am having trouble doing so.  Below is all my code..

The controller:

```
<?php

namespace Issh\MainBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
use Issh\MainBundle\Form\Post\CommentForm;
use Issh\MainBundle\Form\Post\PostForm;
use Issh\MainBundle\Entity\IsshPost;
use Issh\MainBundle\Entity\IsshComment;

class HomeController extends Controller
{

    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('IsshMainBundle:Home:index.html.php');
    }

    public function postAction()
    {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $request = $this->get('request');

        $post = new IsshPost();        
        $form = $this->createForm(new PostForm(), $post);

        if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) 
        {        
            $form->bindRequest($request);           
            $post->setIsshUser($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());

            if ($form->isValid()) 
            {
                $em->persist($post);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
            }
            return $this->render('IsshMainBundle:Home:IsshPost.html.php', array(
                 'form'  =>  $form->createView()));   
        }
        else
        {
            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
            $posts = $em->getRepository('IsshMainBundle:IsshPost')->getLatestPosts();
            return $this->render('IsshMainBundle:Home:IsshPost.html.php', array(
                'form'  =>  $form->createView(), 'posts' => $posts));           
        }

    }

    public function commentAction($postID = null)
    {
        $em = $this->get('doctrine')->getEntityManager();
        $request = $this->get('request');

        $comment = new IsshComment();        
        $form = $this->createForm(new CommentForm($postID), $comment); // need to pass postID here so it can be set as hidden field

        if ('POST' == $request->getMethod()) 
        {        
            $form->bindRequest($request);           
            $comment->setIsshUser($this->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser());  

            if ($form->isValid()) {
                $em->persist($comment);
                $em->flush();

                return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('home'));
            }

        }
        else
        {
            return $this->render('IsshMainBundle:Home:IsshComment.html.php', array(
                'form'  =>  $form->createView()));
        }     
    }
}
```

Here is the post form:

```
<?php

namespace Issh\MainBundle\Form\Post;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class PostForm extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('text','text');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'postForm';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Issh\MainBundle\Entity\IsshPost'
        );
    }
}
?>
```

The comment form (doesn't work yet):

```
<?php

namespace Issh\MainBundle\Form\Post;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilder;

class CommentForm extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('text','text');
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'commentForm';
    }

    public function getDefaultOptions(array $options)
    {
        return array(
            'data_class' => 'Issh\MainBundle\Entity\IsshComment'
        );
    }
}
?>
```

The post template:

```
<?php if(!empty($form)): ?>
<form action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('post') ?>" method="post" <?php echo $view['form']->enctype($form) ?> >
    <?php echo $view['form']->errors($form) ?>
    <?php echo $view['form']->row($form['text']) ?>
    <?php echo $view['form']->rest($form) ?>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(!empty($posts)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($posts as $post): ?>
    <p><?php echo $post->getText();?></p>
    <?php 
    //embed comment controller in view
    echo $view['actions']->render('IsshMainBundle:Home:comment',array('postID' => $post->getId())); 
    ?>
    --------------------------------------
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The comment template:

```
<?php if(!empty($form)): ?>
<form action="<?php echo $view['router']->generate('comment') ?>" method="post" <?php echo $view['form']->enctype($form) ?> >
    <?php echo $view['form']->errors($form) ?>
    <?php echo $view['form']->row($form['text']) ?>
    <?php echo $view['form']->rest($form) ?>
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if(!empty($comments)): ?>
    <?php foreach ($comments as $comment): ?>
    <p><?php echo $comment->getText();?></p>
    --------------------------------------
    <?php endforeach; ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Anybody? I'd really appreciate some help! been stuck on this

Comment: The proper way of dealing that is with "Data Transformers", see http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html

Answer (score 6):

You could declare a constructor in your form class and pass the postID to the form.

```
class CommentForm extends AbstractType
{
    private $postId;

    public function __construct($postId = null)
    {
        $this->postId = $postId;
    }

    public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options)
    {
    ... 
}
```

You can now access the postID as $this->postId anywhere in the form.

Answer (score 3):

You can simply add an options to buildForm method like that:

> $form = $this->get('form.factory')->create(new FormType(), array( 'key' => 'var'));